# Remove item from Realm many to many relationships

Tags: android, realm

I have two classes, Trip and TravelStamp. Trips have many TravelStamps and TravelStamps have Many Trips.

They are declared like this.

```
public class Travelstamp extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private Date timestamp;
private double lat;
private double lon;
private boolean sync;
private Date syncDate;
// getters and setters //
...
}


public class Trip extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String name;
private Date start;
private Date end;
private RealmList<TravelStamp> stamps;
//getters and setters
...
}
```

What I want to do is remove a trip from Realm. I would also like to remove any TravelStamp that is associated with that trip under the condition that the TravelStamp is not associated with any other trips. How would I be able to find out what Trips are associated with a single TravelStamp object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is cascading deletes. It is not implemented in Realm yet, but there is an issue for it here, with some possible work-arounds: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2717

A simple option is implementing your own delete method that could look like this:

```
public class Trip extends RealmObject {
  public RealmList< TravelStamp > stamps;
  ...

  public void cascadeDelete(Realm realm) {
    List<TravelStamp> stampsToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TravelStamp stamp : stamp) {
      if (realm.where(Travel.class).equalTo("stamps.id", stamp.getId()).count() == 1) {
        stampsToDelete.add(stamp);
      }
    }
    for (TravelStamp stamp : stampsToDelete) {
      stamp.deleteFromRealm();
    }
    deleteFromRealm(); // delete this object
  }  
}
```

Comment: This does not check if any of the stamps are associated with other Trips, though

Comment: Your right. I missed that part. That part is a lot more tricky. It will be solved by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2881, but that is not particular helpful right now. For now you could create an extra query in the cascadeDelete() method.